# Is the following limit's property correct?

Tags: calculus, limits

Trying to solve a calculus problem, I run into the first part of following expression and I wanted to simplify it further. The following simplification makes sense to me but I have not been able to find it proven anywhere.

$\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{\lim_{b\rightarrow0} f(b)}{a} = \lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{f(a)}{a} = \lim_{b\rightarrow0} \frac{f(b)}{b}$

Is it really correct to do it that way? If so, how can I prove it form the definition of the limit ($0<|x-a|< \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$) or using another way?

Calculus newbie here xP

Comment: The last equality is trivially true.  The first is not generally true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prove that it will work because it doesn't always work.  When dealing with nested limits, you must always take the inner most limit first and work your way out.  For example,

$$\lim_{a\to0}\frac{\lim_{b\to0}b}a=\lim_{a\to0}\frac0a=0$$

But as you have written,

$$\lim_{a\to0}\frac{\lim_{b\to0}b}a=\lim_{a\to0}\frac aa=1$$

These are known as [iterated limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit), and they also do not satisfy the following in general:

$$\lim_{a\to a_0}\lim_{b\to b_0}f(a,b)\ne\lim_{b\to b_0}\lim_{a\to a_0}f(a,b)$$

As $a(c)\to a_0$ and $b(c)\to b_0$, it is not true in general that:

$$\lim_{a\to a_0}\lim_{b\to b_0}f(a,b)\ne\lim_{c\to c_0}f(a(c),b(c))$$

Comment: Ouch, thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! :-)

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample is easy, for example with $f(x):=\sin x$:

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{\lim_{b\rightarrow0}\sin b}{a} = \lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{0}{a}=0,$$
while
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{\sin a}{a} = \lim_{b\rightarrow0} \frac{\sin b}{b}=1.$$

($f(x):=x$ is even simpler.)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: sorry, I paid no attention.

Comment: No problem :-)  Wasn't much of a problem anyways.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize of that